# two examples of relations with some conditions (transitive, irreflexive, asymmetric)

Tags: relations

I need help with this two exmples, I have no idea.

a example of a relation holds trichotomy and that it is not transitive.

a example of a relation that is irreflexive and that it is not asymmetrical.

R holds trichotomy if $x<y$ or $x=y$ or $y<x$.

Comment: How about we start with you defining the properties in question:  How do you define a relation for which trichotomy holds.  What does it mean for a relation to be transitive?  What  does it mean if a relation is irreflexive? What does it mean for a relation to be asymmetrical?

Comment: To put you on track: try out some relations on a set that has only $2$ elements. There are not so much ($2^4=16$ to be exact).

Comment: Thanks for your edit:  More generally (and this gives you more options for finding an example): "A binary relation $R$ on $X$ is trichotomous if for all $x, y\in X,$ then  exactly one of $xRy, yRx$ or $x=y$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

First counter-example: Consider relation R whose boolean representation is:

$$\pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1}$$

i.e. xRx, yRy, zRz, xRy, yRz and zRx are true and only them.

- Clearly, R is trichotomous,
- whereas R is not transitive because we have xRy and yRz without having xRz.